# Rspec/Capybara checking concatenated string of entire content of page, for expected string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am testing the process of editing products in a rails app. The process is working as expected on my site and all other similar specs are passing. In this instance, when I tell Capybara to expect a string "Product details have been updated" on the page after the form is submitted, it is looking inside another string that is comprised of all of the content on the page concatenated together. Please see the message I'm getting from rspec below and let me know if you need any more information. As you can see, my string is showing up on the page, but rspec can't pick it out.

Message from rspec:

```
  1) edit a product process edits a product 
   Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "Product details have 
   been updated."
   expected to find text "Product details have been updated." in 
   "Welcome to Mario's Specialty Food Products See all products Return 
    to Home Update Hot Dog Product details have been udpated. Name Cost 
    Country Back to Product Page"
```

The failing spec:

```
    require 'rails_helper'

  describe "edit a product process" do
    it "edits a product " do
      product = Product.create(:name => "Hot Dog", :cost => 10, :country => "United States")
      visit products_path
      click_link 'See all products'
      click_link product.name
      click_on "Edit Product Details"
      fill_in "Cost", :with => 7
      click_on "submit"
      expect(page).to have_content "Product details have been updated."
    end
  end
```

The controller:

```
    class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Product details have been udpated."
      render :edit
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

The view:

```
    <div class='card'>
      <h3>Update <%= @product.name%></h3>
      <p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
      <%= render 'form' %>
      <%= link_to 'Back to Product Page', product_path(@product) %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe it can't find it because the page says "udpated" instead of "updated"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your #updated action:

```
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Product details have been udpated."
      render :edit
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Change your flash notice from "udpated" to "updated" and you should be good to go.

Comment: Now *that's* some fine transposition spotting! +1